How to deploy from vs code to azure blob storage static web app?
I am currently working flutter web app and ran the program It worked. Later I planned to host this web app in azure cloud. So I used static web app in azure storage $web container. To build the web application I used the following command

flutter build web

To navigate this file folder/flutter_project/build/web
After building the web application I manually deployed the files by uploading or browsing the required files. Every time I change the program I have to manually do like this What I want is to deploy the application using VS code or cli.
The other thing is we can't directly upload the web folder and access the application because the static web app only require the index.html, name not along with the path so I just extracted the file contents and uploaded it in container separately like below shown


You can deploy using GitHub actions.

Are you able to deploy the application now?

You can deploy the flutter application to Static Web App using GitHub actions.

Create a new repository in GitHub and push your code to it.
Configure the deployment during the creation of Azure Static web app.
Create a Static Web app, navigate to Deployment Details=> Select GitHub as Source=>Select your repository and the branch (of your flutter app)=>Review+Create.



The flutter application gets deployed.
Track the deployment status in GitHub=>your repository=>Actions:


Portal:


I have deployed a flutter app to Static Web App using GitHub actions.


References:
Refer MSdoc to deploy the application to Static Web App using VSCode.
